# Eclipse Java-EE is not auto importing dependencies

Tags: eclipse, jsp, dependencies

I'm using Eclipse for Java-EE and trying to write this basic scriptlet in index.jsp:

```
 <%
 out.pritnln(new Date());
 %>
```

Usually Eclipse will suggest an auto-import of "java.util.Date" class but im not getting a suggestion and instead i'm just getting "Date cannot be resolved to a type". I can manually add this and it will work:

```
<%@ tag import="java.util.Date"%>
```

But why isn't it doing it automatically like regular Eclipse does (non EE one)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Start typing `new Date`, then press `Ctrl+Space`. Auto-completion should trigger and you should be able to import automatically in your JSP.